# can I send an email through a PHP mailer with my localhost without Gmail?

Tags: phpmailer

can I send an email through a PHP mailer with my localhost without using Gmail? or any other email service like Hotmail, outlook using my localhost?

Comment: A free mailgun account is a good way to send mail from localhost

Comment: Technically you can if localhost hosts a mail server or if you have another server to relay the message. If you're asking, you probably don't. The server relaying the message (can be Google's Gmail) will provide you credentials to do it. It is not about having an address to indicate in the From field, it is about being authorized by a mail server to send the message through it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is actually [the best way to send using PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists#maximising-performance). There are two things you need:

1. A hosting provider that permits outbound SMTP. A large number of providers block SMTP by default, but you may find that they will remove the block on request (scaleway.com), provide an alternative service (AWS), which may also be acceptable.
2. A locally installed mail server. If you're on Linux, something like postfix is a good choice.

The way it then works is this:

1. Write your PHPMailer script as normal, but delivering to `localhost` over SMTP (not via `mail()`)
2. Configure your mail server to act as a "full" mail server, where it attempts to deliver messages directly, or to act as a "smarthost" to relay through some other service, such as gmail or mailgun.

The main advantages of this approach are:

1. Perceived performance: your message submissions will appear to be instant, so it's great for things like contact forms
2. Reliability: if your message can't be delivered immediately, the local mail server will automatically take care of queuing and redelivery attempts, in a way that is far more efficient than you would ever achieve if you handled that within your own application.

As with many things, with great power comes great responsibility, and you will have to deal with bounce handling, blacklisting, inbound filtering (or just block it), etc. It's probably not worth doing all this for a simple contact form, but if you have an application that generates a reasonable amount of email traffic (signups, password resets, notifications, etc), it's a great way to go.